# Delete all rows with field beginning

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How to run a query to delete all rows and associated field entries from a table with datefield beginning with 000-00-00

Comment: Seriously, have you made some researchs before asking ?

Answer (score 0):

Your queston isn't very clear, if you want delete all rows with date is like "0000-00-00" :

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE date = '0000-00-00'
```

Or if its a datetime :

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE date = '0000-00-00 *'
```

Comment: What if date is `0000-00-00 12:15:45` ?

Comment: Try with this : '0000-00-00 *'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring_index` and compare for delete

```
mysql> select substring_index('0000-00-00 12:15:45',' ',1);
+----------------------------------------------+
| substring_index('0000-00-00 12:15:45',' ',1) |
+----------------------------------------------+
| 0000-00-00                                   |
+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select substring_index('12:15:45',' ',1);
+-----------------------------------+
| substring_index('12:15:45',' ',1) |
+-----------------------------------+
| 12:15:45                          |
+-----------------------------------+
```

So the delete query may be as

```
delete from 
table_name
where 
substring_index(column_name,' ',1) = '0000-00-00'
```